# Trying to call a constructor of KFCdata(Class) using "This" from kfcTab2(class) extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Please help me it would be great if anyone can get me thought this.
Here i'm trying to send details (EditText, String and Image Button Click) from **kfcTab2.java** to **KFCdata.java**

It shows an error

> KFCdata(android.content.Context)  in KFCdata cannot be applied
>   to(com.packagename)

**kfcTab2.java**

```
public class kfcTab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageButton menu1;
EditText K_No;
String KNo;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kfctab_2,container,false);
    K_No = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.nos);
     menu1 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.kmenu1);
      menu1.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.kmenu1:
                String Name = "Rudresh";
                String order = "Chicken Biriyani";
                KNo = K_No.getText().toString();
                KFCdata BackTask = new KFCdata(this);
                BackTask.execute(Name,order,KNo);
                break;

    }
}
```

}

KFCdata.java

```
public class KFCdata extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context ctx;
KFCdata(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String ORDER_URL = "http://zesto596.96.lt/orders.php";
    String Customer = params[0];
    String Order = params[1];
    String Quantity = params[2];

    try {
        URL url = new URL(ORDER_URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("CUSTOMER","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Customer,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("ITEM","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Order,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("QUANTITY","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Quantity,"UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        OS.close();
        InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        IS.close();
        return "Item Added, please swipe to ORDERS...";
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

**kfcTab2.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:src="@drawable/biryani"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Chicken Biriyani"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="description"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-150sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-150sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nos"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:hint="Nos"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100sp"/>


           <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/kmenu1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/addtoplate"
            android:onClick=""
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: paste your full logcat error message

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your code

this with current activity context

```
KFCdata BackTask = new KFCdata(this.kfcTab2.getActivity()); BackTask.execute(Name,order,KNo); break;
```